# How do i recursively count the number of todos in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion, aggregate, xslt-1.0

One of our service provides a xml document that list collection of todo's. Todo's have been structured to be nestable under a todolist. Every single `todo item` will have parent `todo list`. I need to use XSL to show a count of number of todo-items for the current parent `todo-list`. Please find the structure of the xml below

```
<TodoListCollection>
  <TodoList>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <ParentId></ParentId>
    <Count>3</Count>
    <TodoItemCollection>
      <TodoItem></TodoItem>
      <TodoItem></TodoItem>
      <TodoItem></TodoItem>
    </TodoItemCollection>
  </TodoList>
  <TodoList>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <ParentId>1</ParentId>
    <Count>4</Count>
    <TodoItemCollection>
      <TodoItem></TodoItem>
      <TodoItem></TodoItem>
      <TodoItem></TodoItem>
      <TodoItem></TodoItem>
    </TodoItemCollection>
  </TodoList>
</TodoListCollection>
```

In first iteration for `TodoList ID = 1`, i should be able to get count as `3 + 4 = 7` in  total. As there are **3** in first todo item collection and then **4** in the child todo item collection (`ParentId = 1`). Nesting here is just one level but we have designed it to be N-level.

**Note:**
You can try your queries online over here http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kChildren" match="TodoList" use="ParentId"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kChildren', '')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:variable name="vPass1" select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$vPass1/*" mode="pass2"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="TodoList">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kChildren', Id)"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="pass2">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="pass2"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="TodoList" mode="pass2">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::TodoList)]" mode="pass2"/>
   </xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="TodoList" mode="pass2"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Count" mode="pass2">
  <Count>
   <xsl:value-of select="sum(..//Count)"/>
  </Count>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (based on the provided, but with deeper hierarchy):

```
<TodoListCollection>
    <TodoList>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <ParentId></ParentId>
        <Count>3</Count>
        <TodoItemCollection>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
        </TodoItemCollection>
    </TodoList>
    <TodoList>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <ParentId>1</ParentId>
        <Count>7</Count>
        <TodoItemCollection>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
        </TodoItemCollection>
    </TodoList>
    <TodoList>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <ParentId>2</ParentId>
        <Count>5</Count>
        <TodoItemCollection>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
        </TodoItemCollection>
    </TodoList>
    <TodoList>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <ParentId>3</ParentId>
        <Count>3</Count>
        <TodoItemCollection>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
        </TodoItemCollection>
    </TodoList>
    <TodoList>
        <Id>5</Id>
        <ParentId>2</ParentId>
        <Count>1</Count>
        <TodoItemCollection>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
            <TodoItem></TodoItem>
        </TodoItemCollection>
    </TodoList>
</TodoListCollection>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<TodoListCollection>
   <TodoList>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <ParentId/>
      <Count>19</Count>
      <TodoItemCollection>
         <TodoItem/>
         <TodoItem/>
         <TodoItem/>
      </TodoItemCollection>
   </TodoList>
   <TodoList>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <ParentId>1</ParentId>
      <Count>16</Count>
      <TodoItemCollection>
         <TodoItem/>
         <TodoItem/>
         <TodoItem/>
         <TodoItem/>
      </TodoItemCollection>
   </TodoList>
   <TodoList>
      <Id>3</Id>
      <ParentId>2</ParentId>
      <Count>8</Count>
      <TodoItemCollection>
         <TodoItem/>
         <TodoItem/>
         <TodoItem/>
         <TodoItem/>
      </TodoItemCollection>
   </TodoList>
   <TodoList>
      <Id>4</Id>
      <ParentId>3</ParentId>
      <Count>3</Count>
      <TodoItemCollection>
         <TodoItem/>
         <TodoItem/>
         <TodoItem/>
         <TodoItem/>
      </TodoItemCollection>
   </TodoList>
   <TodoList>
      <Id>5</Id>
      <ParentId>2</ParentId>
      <Count>1</Count>
      <TodoItemCollection>
         <TodoItem/>
         <TodoItem/>
         <TodoItem/>
         <TodoItem/>
      </TodoItemCollection>
   </TodoList>
</TodoListCollection>
```

**Explanation**:

This is a two-pass transformation:

1. In the first pass the document is converted from flat to hierarchical based on the parent --> id relation.
2. In the second pass the result of pass1 is converted back to a flat document. `Count` elements are adjusted to contain the sum of all `Count` elements in their innermost containing subtree.
3. A third pass may be needed if we want the final result to contain the `TodoList` elements sorted by their `Id`.

Comment: +1 Does what it says, but recursion could have been more friendlier in XSLT. Syntax and Idea is fantastic